# How many blocks (or partitions) does spark load from the HDFS at the first time when action is performed?

Tags: apache-spark

I want to know data flow from hdfs to spark job in detail when spark job is executed. As far as I know, when `sc.textFile("...")` and the action command are executed, the data stored in the HDFS is partitioned and then they are loaded to the spark-side. For example, there are 30Gb data in the HDFS, and action is performed, then the the number of partitions(maybe, 30Gb/128Mb,default) are created,they are distributed to the worker nodes and spark will process the partitioned data.

When the worker node's memory is not sufficient (ex. 500mb or 1Gb/node), I think that the partitions that are passed to each worker node cannot be inside the memory at the same time. Therefore, I think that each node processes a few partitions out of the total partitions that they will have to deal with, and then swaps the processed partitions into disk and then takes the next partitions. In this process, worker node can process all the partitions even in the memory resources are not large.

In this process, I think that spark can deal with a lot of data even though they have small memory resources. However, when I experimented above concept with the data, I faced the java heap space error. Of course, my code has different transformations including `sc.textFile("...")`, but it has very basic operations as shown in below.

```
JavaRDD<String> data = sc.textFile("...")

JavaPairRDD<String, List<String>> retRDD = data.flatMapToPair(new PairFlatMapFunction<String, String, List<String>>() {
                @Override
                public Iterable<Tuple2<String, List<String>>> call(String s) throws Exception {
                    List<Tuple2<String, List<String>>> rtn = new ArrayList<Tuple2<String, List<String>>>();
                    String s1 = s;
                    String []splitted = s1.split("\t");

                    long ckAsLong = Long.parseLong(splitted[2]);
                    int batchId = (int) (ckAsLong / batchSize);
                    List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();

                    temp.add(splitted[2] + "\t" + splitted[3]);

                    rtn.add(new Tuple2<String, List<String>>(
                            splitted[0] + "\t" + splitted[1] + "\t" + batchId + "\t",
                            temp
                    ));

                    return rtn;
                }
            });



retRDD.count() //action is performed
```

I have four nodes and I gave each node 500mb then the heap space error occurred at the very earlier step when I ran the spark-summit. When giving 1Gb to the node, the program was completed without error.

Based on my experience, I think that spark job tries to load the specific partitions from the total partitions and then processes them. For example, the 10 partitions are assigned to the node1, then node1 processes the 3 out of 10 at first and then moves them into the disk and then load next partitions and so on. Because I think that the total sizeof specific partitions is above the executor's memory size, the java heap space occurred.

My questions is as below.
If my guess is right, how to figure out the specific partitions that spark loads form the HDFS at the first time when the memory is not enough? Otherwise can you correct my assumptions so that I can understand spark concept in an accurate way.

Thanks!